# Using a category in View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, categories

I have a category with the function:

Users+Authentication.m

```
- (BOOL) isUniqueUsername:(NSString *)username
{
    return YES or NO;
}
```

Users is a subclass of my table called users.  In my view controller, how do I call this method correctly?

In view controller:

```
BOOL isUnique = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your view controller, add

```
#import "Users+Authentication.h"
```

to make the methods declared there available for use.

```
BOOL isUnique = [self isUniqueUsername:username];
```

As long as `self` is the object being categorized.

Comment: I get a RegisterViewController does not have the method for isUniqueUsername error

Comment: Then self is not the object being categorized. You said it was a tableView class being categorized right? try self.tableView

Comment: No it's a subclass of my table in SQLite

Comment: Users+Authentication.h contains a category of which class exactly?

Comment: The users class which is a subclass of my Users table. So I have a Users.h and Users.m file that was autogenerated from my model

Comment: ok perfect, so you need to call the isUniqueUsername on a user instance. so something like [user isUniqueUsername:username]